# TypeError: integer argument expected, got float, python 3.6.3 with pygame

Tags: python, pygame, typeerror

I am having problem with my python game, it's my first project. I am getting an error (TypeError: integer argument expected, got float). It's starting to come when I insert my user-defined function shoot. How to solve this problem or make a SuperMario image shoot a circular object with a class. Thanks :)

```
import pygame
import time

pygame.init()

display_height = 600
display_width = 800

white = (255,255,255)

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Igra1')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

bg = pygame.image.load('background.jpg')
bg = pygame.transform.scale(bg,(800, 600))

Img_SuperMario = pygame.image.load('SuperMario.png')
SuperMario_width = 611
SuperMario_height = 611
Img_SuperMario = pygame.transform.scale(Img_SuperMario, (100, 100))

def shoot(xshoot):
    while xshoot < display_width:
        pygame.draw.circle(gameDisplay, white, (xshoot,50), 20 ,0)
        xshoot += 10

def SuperMario(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(Img_SuperMario,(x,y))

def gameloop():

x = (display_width * 0.1)
y = (display_height * 0.1)

x_change = 0
y_change = 0

game_exit = False

while not game_exit:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if  event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x_change = -5
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_change = 5
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                y_change = -5
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                y_change = 5

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN or event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                x_change = 0
                y_change = 0


    if x == display_width - 100 or x == 0:
        x_change = 0

    if y == (display_height - 100) or y == 0:
        y_change = 0


    x += x_change
    y += y_change
    xshoot = x

    gameDisplay.fill(white)
    gameDisplay.blit(bg,(0,0))

    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                while xshoot < display_width:
                    shoot(x)
    SuperMario(x,y)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)

gameloop()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: Try to incorporate which line the errors occur next time. It will make it easier to trace the error.

Comment: always put full error message (Traceback) in question (as text, not screenshot). There are other useful informations.

Comment: error message should show you where is problem and then you should use `print()` and `print(type(...))` to check values and types in variables to find variable which has `float` value, and then you should use `int()`.

Comment: You need to search for tutorials or other answers about bullets on SO. Your approach with the other while loops won't work. A very basic solution would be to store the bullet positions in a list and add the bullet velocity to the positions every frame. Use `for` loops to update and draw the bullets.

Answer (score 1):

The `pygame.draw.circle` function only accepts integers, but your `x` variable is a float. Convert the `xshoot` variable to an integer in the `shoot` function, e.g.:

```
pygame.draw.circle(gameDisplay, white, (int(xshoot), 50), 20 ,0)
```

It looks like you also need to change the `while xshoot < display_width:` loops in the main loop and the `shoot` function, but I'm not sure what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

`x = int((display_width * 0.1))
y = int((display_height * 0.1))`

try parse to int, maybe will work.