# Expected type 'int' got 'float' instead

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
weight_lbs = input ('weight (lbs): ')
weight_kg = int(weight_lbs * 0.45)
print(weight_kg)
```

> Error: Expected type 'int' got 'float' instead.

Kindly advise.

Comment: you need to change the title to the error message for example. and try to wrap the code between ```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: integer argument expected, got float, python 3.6.3 with pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981151/typeerror-integer-argument-expected-got-float-python-3-6-3-with-pygame)

Answer (score 3):

I tried your code and I don't get the same problem, though I saw a different problem.

This code:

```py
weight_kg = int(weight_lbs * 0.5)
```

Should be:

```py
weight_kg = int(weight_lbs) * 0.5
```

Otherwise, you'll get this error:

> TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

The reason is your code is multiplying a string by a number. You need first to convert the string returned by `input()` to a number, and then do the multiplication.

Comment: int should be float

Comment: That depends on what the OP wants.

Comment: well, your code breaks if I weight 33.4 lbs

Comment: Is that valid input for OP's problem? There is not enough information in the question to know that for sure.

Comment: who knows :-) .. A weight is usually a float though

Comment: Thanks, MondKin. Indeed your answer is correct. The closing parenthesis sign should come before the multiplication sign. The code works well now.

Comment: @Kebasita I'm glad it worked. Also pay attention to whether you need an `int` or a `float`, as others have mentioned, your current code works only when the weight is an int, if that's not what you need, then use the `float` function instead.

Answer (score 2):

Your input `weight_lbs` is a string, not a number. Convert it to `int` or `float`

```
weight_kg = int( float(weight_lbs) * 0.5)
```

(Also, a pound is not half a kilogram. Why not be more accurate? You do have a computer!)

Comment: int should be removed (I guess) - or you need to remove the last sentence asking for accuracy

Comment: @chris-p-bacon that’s hard to tell really ... OP might want integers, they already are explicitly trying to cast something

Comment: @chris-p-bacon One of these choices is about how they wish to represent data, the other is a misrepresentation of the relative relationship of measures.

Comment: It is correct to multiply by 0.45.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
weight_lbs = input('weight (lbs): ')
weight_kg = int(float(weight_lbs) * 0.5)
print(weight_kg)
```

Comment: Hi Nikos. This code also works.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

```
weight_lbs = input('weight (lbs): ')
# I just converted the type of "weight_lbs" to Float and removed the last parenthesis 
weight_kg = float(weight_lbs) * 0.5
print(weight_kg)
```

Comment: This works too. The problem was with the position of the closing parenthesis sign.